# VBA loop through columns and check for specific color of cells

Tags: vba, loops

I am trying to loop through a range by column. When a specific color is detected in any cell within the column, it should go to the next column. Or, if the color is not present at all, mark a cell in a specific row. Should look like this:[image]

With my current code, it is not always hitting the right cell, that needs to be marked. Can anyone help please?

```
Dim rng, cell, col As Range
Dim colcount, Lcount As Integer

Set rng = Sheet2.Range("B2:J4")

For Each col In rng.Columns
    For Each cell In col.Cells
        If cell.Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent5 Then
            Lcount = Lcount + 1
            colcount = cell.Column
        End If
    Next cell
    If Lcount >= 1 Then
        Lcount = 0
        GoTo Continues
    Else
        With Sheet2.Cells(5, colcount).Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
        End With
    End If
Continues:
Next col
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Sometimes one does not see the forrest through the trees

```
Dim rng, cell, col As Range
Dim colcount, Lcount As Integer

Set rng = Sheet2.Range("B2:J4")

For Each col In rng.Columns
    For Each cell In col.Cells
        If cell.Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent5 Then
            Lcount = Lcount + 1
        Else
            colcount = cell.Column
        End If
    Next cell
    If Lcount > 0 Then
        Lcount = 0
        GoTo Continues
    Else
        With Sheet2.Cells(5, colcount).Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
        End With
    End If
Continues:
Next col
```